# Symfony2 dispatching INTERACTIVE_LOGIN event + redirects

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, symfony-2.8

I have an issue with Symfony2 event dispatcher regarding `INTERACTIVE_LOGIN` event.

Now I have two scenarios:

1. Login - when user is signing in, they get redirected to google and after authenticating they are taken back, if the account is found he's authenticated and then I have a success handler implementing `AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface` and inside this handler I redirect user to a specific URL based on different parameters. Now, this one works just fine, it does what it's meant to do.
2. Registration - when user is signing in, they get redirected to google and after authenticating they are taken back, just like with login scenario. Now, here the account is not found and the user is being redirected to registration form. When the registration is completed and verified, I manually dispatch `INTERACTIVE_LOGIN` event. The success handler is once again executed. I would expect the redirect response to work, but it does not. Instead it proceeds further with my controller's action.

So the question is, is this behaviour expected when manually dispatching this event? Can it be changed so it does actually use the redirect response returned from success handler?

Comment: Events are fire and forget so yes this is the expected behavior.  When you redirect you actually return a RedirectResponse object which does not get processed until later in the cycle.  It is not an immediate thing.  You could of course just have the user login after registering.  If you dig into the security code you will see that the INTERACTIVE_LOGIN listener already assumes that the user is properly logged in and does not call the success handler. http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authentication.html#security-events

Comment: Someone else may have already solved this problem.  All I can suggest is that you extract your redirect code and make it available to your controller.

Comment: @Cerad so let me understand it. When the `INTERACTIVE_LOGIN` event is dispatched by the firewall / authenticator (I don't remember where it is being triggered now), then the response returned from `onLoginSuccessHandler` is later handled by a listener that does send the `RedirectResponse` and if I dispatch it manually, I also have to manually handle the redirect response (except I can't, because I have no access to it outside listener). I always have problem remembering what execute what in authentication component. Anyway, this is what I've done so far, thought there may be better solution.

Comment: Take a look at the Firewall/AbstractAuthenticationListener.  Basically it fires the INTERACTIVE_LOGIN event before calling the success handler.  And yes the security code is complicated.  The event name is perhaps a bit unfortunate.  It sort of implies that it does the interactive login but in reality it get's fired after a successful login. In fact, I don't think the basic framework even handles the event.